# Set a Base Target for All Links in Container

Tags: javascript, html, css

Is it possible to set a default target for all links inside `article.blank` to, for example, `_blank`, without explicitly changing each link's target?

```
<a href='https://example.com'>Don't change my target.</a>
<article class='blank'>
  <h1>Hello, World!</h1>
  <p>Well, hello? Follow <a href='https://example.com'>the link</a>, blah-blah.</p>
</article>
<article class='blank'>
  <h1>Lorem Ipsum</h1>
  <p>Dolor sit amet? <a href='https://example.com'>Lingua latina</a> non penis canis est.</p>
</article>
```

Comment: did you really accept the below answer and it worked for you?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can define this property in the CSS file on global selector to get all the elements this.
update your css file to:

```
* {
   target: "_blank";
}
```

Comment: No such property was found in W3C specifications.  Also, modern browsers consider `target` property invalid.

Comment: This is an invalid CSS property and doesn't work for modern browsers (see [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target.asp)).

Answer (score 1):

You can set the base target for all the  tags in the document by

```
<head>
  <base target="_blank">
</head>
```

and Where you need to have specific target, you can override it by

```
<a target="different target"> </a>
```

Comment: While your answer is the only one getting close to being correct, it doesn't allow only setting the base target for the links *"in container"* (as required), but rather sets the base target for ***"all links in the document"***. Also note only the first `<base>` tag is considered, subsequent ones are ignored.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one `jQuery(".blank a").attr("target","_blank");`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to explain how it solves the problem without introducing others and why to use it. Code-only answers are [not useful in the long run](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/300837/what-comment-should-i-add-to-code-only-answers/300846#300846).

Answer (score -1):

Update this property in main css

```
* {
   target: "_blank";
}
```

Comment: This is an invalid CSS property and doesn't work for modern browsers (see [w3schools.com](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_target.asp)).